# Logitech h250 headset microphone does not output voice

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone

My **Logitech h250** headset was working for 5 months, then all of a sudden the microphone doesn't output anything but wind. The audio output works fine, but when I listen to a microphone recording, all I can hear is some windy sound.

I recently tripped over my laptop, causing the headphones to be plugged out. Roughly. May that be the issue?

I tried reinstalling the audio driver, plugging it in and out, restarting the computer, messing with the audio settings, all to no avail.

Any solutions are greatly appreciated.

Audio ports: 3.5mm Mic and Audio jacks

OS : Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium

Audio Driver : Realtek HD Audio

Comment: +1, excellent, clear and well formatted first question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test with a different headset to determine if the fault is with just the headset.

If others work fine, then you need to repair or buy a new headset and this is outside the scope of the site.

If others headsets do not work, then this could indicate a fault with the socket itself (when you tripped over the machine) or a driver issue or even some other hardware fault... You can confirm by recording "what you hear" (if the option is available) or by using an external mic (if the PC has one).

Comment: Seems like the headset itself is damaged. I'll need to replace mine.